# Blogger API in android application show only 10 posts

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-blogger-api

I create a app in android studio using Blogger API. but in my app after launch it show only 10 posts but in my blogger have more then 10 post. Please give me a solution for the same.

Comment: Can you post the code to let others check what you are trying to do?

Comment: put your blog address and api

Answer (score 0):

By default the [blogger API](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference) only returns 10 posts per request. You can change this by adding `maxResults=50` as a parameter in your request. See [here](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts/list).

I believe there is a limit to how many posts you can fetch even with this parameter. It may actually be 50, I forget. So, you may want to also use the paging feature, to fetch "the next 50 posts", if you have more posts than can be handled by a single fetch.

To do this, you need to include `nextPageToken` in your request - for example, as follows:

```
fields=nextPageToken,items(title,url,published)
```

...and whatever other attributes you may want to fetch.

Now, the response you get back from the blogger API will include an additional "next page token" value (`nextPageToken=DgkICheAxTJ1gcQ5vmT9OXn5xZU`).

To use the "next page" token, you have to append it to the query parameters of your next API call - for example:

`pageToken=DgkICheAxTJ1gcQ5vmT9OXn5xZU`

And then repeat the process for each subsequent call, until there are no more "next pages".

Note - the request parameter you need to *send* is `pageToken`, (not the same as what you *receive*, which is `nextPageToken`).